# Listening on netTcpBinding in a web site?

Tags: wcf, iis-7

My first experiment was to host via **APPLICATION** - under the defaultWebSite - my wcf service  - with **netTbpBinding** and it **worked**. ( the 'sss' in the pic)

Now i want to test if i can host it directly under a website. (ppp in the pic)
I gave ppp to listen only yo net.Tcp.

in my endpoint I'm doing like this :

```
net.tcp://localhost/service.svc
```

the picture : 
( why the red X ?) i just referenced it to the site as i was doing before with the application.

[image]

but I'm getting an error :

> Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost/service.svc. The connection
>   attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0050575. TCP error code
>   10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:808.

Comment: What do you see if you hover the mouse over the read "X"?

Answer (score 1):

IIS does not support non-HTTP bindings, such as NetTcpBinding. You must use [Windows Activation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx) or [self-hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) (e.g. in a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)).

Comment: Also make sure that Net.Tcp Listener Adapter service is running

Answer (score 0):

You indicated that your service ran fine under the Default Web Site with NetTcpBinding, so I think there are a couple of things to check/try:

1. Check the site "ppp" and ensure that it has net.tcp enabled in the bindings.  In IIS 7, select Bindings under Actions in the left hand column, and a window will pop up showing the currently enabled bindings.  If it's not listed, you can add it (select net.tcp from the drop down, and enter 808:* in the Binding Information box.
2. Create the service in site "ppp" as an application (like "sss" under your Default WebSite).  I'm not sure putting the service in the root will work (it might).

If neither of those help, let us know what you see if you hover over the red "X" as John Saunders asked.